# Change the source code of timelineJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timeline

Here I have a code for creating interactive timeline: http://timeline.verite.co/

So I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var timeline_config = {
            width:              '100%',
            height:             '600',
            source:             'path_to_json/or_link_to_googlespreadsheet',
            embed_id:           'timeline-embed',               //OPTIONAL USE A DIFFERENT DIV ID FOR EMBED
            start_at_end:       false,                          //OPTIONAL START AT LATEST DATE
            start_at_slide:     '4',                            //OPTIONAL START AT SPECIFIC SLIDE
            start_zoom_adjust:  '3',                            //OPTIONAL TWEAK THE DEFAULT ZOOM LEVEL
            hash_bookmark:      true,                           //OPTIONAL LOCATION BAR HASHES
            font:               'Bevan-PotanoSans',             //OPTIONAL FONT
            debug:              true,                           //OPTIONAL DEBUG TO CONSOLE
            lang:               'fr',                           //OPTIONAL LANGUAGE
            maptype:            'watercolor',                   //OPTIONAL MAP STYLE
            css:                'path_to_css/timeline.css',     //OPTIONAL PATH TO CSS
            js:                 'path_to_js/timeline-min.js'    //OPTIONAL PATH TO JS
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
```

and this code produce Timeline + Media... so like this on image but I want to know how I can remove the all part except timeline on the bottom?

HERE IS IMAGE: [image]

Comment: Yes but script will produce this code again

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line in timeline-min.js

u = VMM.appendAndGetElement(s, "", "vco-slider");